# Connect ASP.net web site with outlook calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sharepoint, outlook-2010

I have made one web site for configuring time slot for particular date. For example I stored Email id of user, date, Stating time of lecture, Ending time of lecture in database.

I want to display pop up on desktop before 5 minute of starting time.

Suppose I connect my database with outlook calendar.

How can I connect with outlook?

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

If you deal with Exchange profiles only consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information. Or just use the System.Net namespace classes for accessing your mailbox.